# Stop/Start Microsoft Windows Cluster roles with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cluster-computing, failover

I am new to Microsoft Windows clustering, and we have an environment in which it is required that we bring 'clustered roles' down and up on schedule. Currently, I have been manually processing this, but would like to automate it using Powershell.

I have read through the Cmdlets [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847239(v=wps.630).aspx) , but can't seem to find one that references roles specifically. I was looking at the commands to stop the entire cluster, but that looks like it will take down resources that are not covered by the two roles that I am specifically required to take down.

Example of role I would like to bring down:

[image: here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Stop-ClusterResource`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847306%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) is your friend. This cmdlet takes one selected part of cluster (one resource) offline. Then you can `Start-ClusterResource` at the desired time.

Comment: Thank you, once I began testing with that I was able to bring each resource of the role down that I required.

Answer (score 1):

Stop/Start/Query Microsoft Windows Cluster Roles with Powershell [Tested in Windows Server 2012-R2]

```
C:\>powershell Stop-ClusterGroup "ARCSDE52"

Name                       OwnerNode                  State
----                       ---------                  -----
ARCSDE52                   PRODNODE_AC                Offline


C:\>powershell Get-ClusterGroup "ARCSDE52"

Name                       OwnerNode                  State
----                       ---------                  -----
ARCSDE52                   PRODNODE_AC                Offline


C:\>powershell Start-ClusterGroup "ARCSDE52" -Wait 0

Name                       OwnerNode                  State
----                       ---------                  -----
ARCSDE52                   PRODNODE_AC                Pending


C:\>powershell Get-ClusterGroup "ARCSDE52"

Name                       OwnerNode                  State
----                       ---------                  -----
ARCSDE52                   PRODNODE_AC                Online
```